# installing aurelia-mask for auerlia project

Tags: aurelia

I followed the gui [here](https://github.com/ariovistus/aurelia-mask) to install the aurelia mask and to use it. But now when i load the page i keep getting Error: "Cannot find module './aurelia-mask/masked-input'.". I dont understand what am i doing wrong. How do you add new modules to aurelia project?

in main.ts:

```
.globalResources(PLATFORM.moduleName("aurelia-mask/masked-input"));
```

and in the html file:

```
<require from="aurelia-mask/masked-input"></require>
  <input masked="value.bind: labelCode; mask:9999" class="form-control" id="label_code" autocomplete="off" keyup.delegate="validate()">
```

Comment: From that doc, it seems you only need to specify `aurelia-mask`: `.globalResources(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-mask'))`, can you try that?